# How to show dynamically added product on catalog search

Tags: magento, product, catalog

I have added one attribute in magento admin panel. **eg.**attribute name = Manufacturer
Then I create a relation between Manufacture to Product using catalog_product_entity_int  table in magento.
Then after i went on Adminpanel and try to edit product and there is Manufactuer Attibute is show selected in that product means attribute is properly bind with that product.
But then i went to catalog advance search in front end that product doesn't show up in list.
I also added that Manufacturer value text in catalogsearch_fulltext table by PIPE "|" seperated.

is there any thing missing.??

Comment: Have you set "Use in Advanced Search" value to "Yes" from Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes?

Answer (score 0):

In the admin go to:

> Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes

Search for your attribute and in "Frontend Properties" put "Use in Advanced Search" and "Use in Quick Search" in "Yes".

After that refresh all caches and reindex "Catalog Search Index".

Maybe it solves the problem.

Hope it helps.